# angularjs custom validator for two related inputs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am pretty new to AngularJs and this is the first time I have to make a custom validator. I have a form that has, among others, two numeric inputs, one for hours and one for minutes. I need to validate that if one of the inputs is 0 (the hours input), the minutes input is not 0. But this has to happen when any of them changes value. This is what I came up with so far, but doesn't work right.

```
HTML

 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate name="newActivityForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Duration (hours : minutes)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="number" min="0" max="24" class="form-control" maxlength="2" id="durationHours" name="durationHours" ng-model="activity.durationHours" minutes-required-when-duration-hours-is-zero required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationHours.$error.required && !newActivityForm.durationHours.$error.number" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration hours field is required">*</span>
      <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationHours.$error.number" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration hours field must be a number">*</span>
      <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationHours.$error.max" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration hours field must be less than or equal to 24">*</span>
      <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationHours.$error.min" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration hours field must be greater than or equal to 0">*</span>
      <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.$error.zeroHoursMinutesGreaterThanZeroVld" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="If hours equal 0, minutes must be greater than 0">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="number" min="0" max="59" class="form-control" maxlength="2" id="durationMinutes" name="durationMinutes" ng-model="activity.durationMinutes" minutes-required-when-duration-hours-is-zero required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationMinutes.$error.required && !newActivityForm.durationMinutes.$error.number" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration minutes field is required">*</span>
      <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationMinutes.$error.number" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration minutes field must be a number">*</span>
      <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationMinutes.$error.max" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration minutes field must be less than or equal to 59">*</span>
      <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationMinutes.$error.min" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration minutes field must be greater than or equal to 0">*</span>
      <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.$error.zeroHoursMinutesGreaterThanZeroVld" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="If hours equal 0, minutes must be greater than 0">*</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and the `minutes-required-when-duration-hours-is-zero DIRECTIVE`

```
 app.directive('minutesRequiredWhenDurationHoursIsZero', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          function validate(value) {
            if (scope.activity !== undefined && scope.activity.durationHours === 0 && scope.activity.durationMinutes === 0) {
              ngModel.$setValidity('zeroHoursMinutesGreaterThanZeroVld', false);
            } else {
              ngModel.$setValidity('zeroHoursMinutesGreaterThanZeroVld', true);
            }
          }

          scope.$watch(function() {
            return ngModel.$viewValue;
          }, validate);
        }
      };
    });
```

So this form opens with hours filled with 8 and minutes with 0. If I write 0 to the hours, both validation stars appear (for hours and minutes). If I go to the minutes and write in a number, the stars don't disappear. I figured it out that it is because the ngModel of the hours is invalid, but when I change the minutes, how can I set the hours' ngModel to valid again?

Comment: add this on the minutes inputs `ng-required="activity.durationHours != 0"`, you dont need custom directive for this

Comment: @HarishR this only makes the minutes input need a value, meaning user can use 0 too. So if I do this, if hours are 0, minutes are required. The activity cannot be 0 hours 0 minutes. It must be at least 0 hours 1 minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for it:

```
<div class="form-group" minutes-required-when-duration-hours-is-zero ng-model="activity" hours="durationHours" minutes="durationMinutes">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Duration (hours : minutes)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="24" class="form-control" maxlength="2" id="durationHours" name="durationHours" placeholder="hours" ng-model="activity.durationHours" required />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationHours.$error.required && !newActivityForm.durationHours.$error.number" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration hours field is required">*</span>
        <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationHours.$error.number" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration hours field must be a number">*</span>
        <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationHours.$error.max" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration hours field must be less than or equal to 24">*</span>
        <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationHours.$error.min" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration hours field must be greater than or equal to 0">*</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="59" class="form-control" maxlength="2" id="durationMinutes" name="durationMinutes" placeholder="minutes" ng-model="activity.durationMinutes" required />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationMinutes.$error.required && !newActivityForm.durationMinutes.$error.number" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration minutes field is required">*</span>
        <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationMinutes.$error.number" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration minutes field must be a number">*</span>
        <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationMinutes.$error.max" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration minutes field must be less than or equal to 59">*</span>
        <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.durationMinutes.$error.min" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Duration minutes field must be greater than or equal to 0">*</span>
        <span class="error" data-ng-show="newActivityForm.$error.zeroHoursMinutesGreaterThanZeroVld" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="If hours equal 0, minutes must be greater than 0">*</span
      </div>
 </div>
```

and the js:

```
app.directive('minutesRequiredWhenDurationHoursIsZero', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

          function validate() {

            var activity = ngModel.$modelValue;

            if (!activity) {
              return;
            }

            var durationHours = activity[attrs['hours']];
            var durationMinutes = activity[attrs['minutes']];

            if (durationHours === 0 && durationMinutes === 0) {
              ngModel.$setValidity('zeroHoursMinutesGreaterThanZeroVld', false);
            } else {
              ngModel.$setValidity('zeroHoursMinutesGreaterThanZeroVld', true);
            }
          }

          scope.$watch(function(newValue, oldValue) {
            validate();
          });
        }
      };
    });
```